# Laravel - Can't save files to public_path using storeAs

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I cannot upload files to the public_path folder in Laravel 5.4. I can't understand what's going wrong, [the documentation makes it look easy](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/filesystem#file-uploads). `$request` is the POSTed contents of a form. `filename` is a file submitted via the form.

```
public function uploadFile($request) {

    if ($request->hasFile('filename') && $request->file('filename')->isValid()) {
        $file = $request->filename;

        $hash = uniqid(rand(10000,99999), true);

        $directory = public_path('files/'.$hash);

        if(File::makeDirectory($directory, 0775, true)) {
            return $file->storeAs($directory, $file->getClientOriginalName());
        }
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

The directory is created, but there's no file inside. As you can see, the folder has 775 permissions.

I've tried added a trailing slash. I've tried removing `public_path` altogether. Nothing works.

What am I doing wrong? :(

Comment: does the directory with name 605915955555e4973a6.15945923 exist?

Comment: @SR_ I've read that on a Linux based system it doesn't need to, but I'll add something to create it if it doesn't and see if that helps. Thanks.

Comment: it works???????

Comment: @SR_ Thanks! Creating the directory fixed the creation of the thumbnail, but strangely the original file (via `saveAs`) isn't stored. I can narrow my question down to a single problem now. Thanks very much.

Comment: updated the answer

Answer (score 10):

By default file system use your default disk named **'local'** that upload files in storage/app folder store using **store**, **stroeAs** etc...

The filesystem configuration file is located at config/filesystems.php.

either you can change root path under 'local'

from `'root' => storage_path('app'),` to `'root' => public_path('files'),`

and then in your code change from

`$directory = public_path('files/'.$hash);` to `$directory = public_path($hash);`

OR you can create new disk in config/filesystem.php

```
'disks' => [

        'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app'),
        ],

        'my_upload' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => public_path('files'),
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],
```

and then mention new disk as below while storing file

```
$file->storeAs($directory, $file->getClientOriginalName(), 'my_upload');
```

After performing all above if not work hit below commands in order

```
php artisan config:clear

php artisan cache:clear

php artisan config:cache
```

Answer (score -3):

You can try this :

```
if(File::makeDirectory($directory, 0775, true)) {
  return $file->store($directory, $file->getClientOriginalName());
}
```

Hope this help you !