# Image uploaded in Laravel 5.8 keep saving as private image

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying upload a single image into a Post and it keeps saving it as a private image--heck, I don't even know where to find that file.

**PostController.php**

```
...
if ($request->hasFile('photo')) {
    $photo = $request->photo;
    $ext = $photo->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $filename = uniqid() . '.' . $ext;
    $photo->storeAs('public/posts/' . $request->user()->id, $filename);
}
...
```

[image]

Comment: See this answer, hope it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44858826/6000629

Comment: Have you checked your storage folder?

Comment: if you are getting wrong public path use this public_path('posts')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

storeAs() function takes three parameters.

```
storeAs(path,name,options)
```

'options' is where you specify file visibility. In your case :

```
if ($request->hasFile('photo')) {
    $photo = $request->photo;
    $ext = $photo->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $filename = uniqid() . '.' . $ext;
    $photo->storeAs('posts/' . $request->user()->id, $filename,'public');
}
```